# Remove tag synonym x64 -> 64bit

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

The wiki for [64bit](/questions/tagged/64bit) reads:

> A 64-bit architecture is usually a system where addresses (pointers) are 64 bits wide. Sometimes, it can mean a system where the "natural" size for integer computations (the word size) is 64 bits.

This is clearly talking about 64 bit architectures in general. The tag [64bit](/questions/tagged/64bit) has [x64](/questions/tagged/x64) as a synonym, but that specifically refers to the 64 bit extension of IA-32, and not 64 bit architectures in general. This synonym relationship should be removed and [x64](/questions/tagged/x64) should be a master tag.

Comment: I guess there have been users who used [tag:x64] to mean "this is a question about a 64-bit CPU" and re-tagging all the questions was too time-consuming.

Comment: +1, synonym doesn't make sense here.

Comment: x64 should be mapped to x86-64 instead.